How to Bypass HTTPS in Apache NiFi When Connecting to External APIs?
I'm currently working with Apache NiFi and need to connect to an external API that uses HTTPS. However, for testing purposes, I need to bypass HTTPS verification to simplify the integration process. Is there a way to configure NiFi to skip HTTPS verification when making requests to these external APIs?
Here are the details of my setup:

NiFi Version: 1.26.0
Processor(s) Used: HandleHTTPRequests

Any guidance or examples of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

There is no straightforward way to do that, as some versions of NiFi have disabled calling invalid SSL endpoints. As a workaround, I am using the ExecuteStreamCommand processor and using curl to call the API.
